# How to delete Pyenv

Tags: python, pyenv

I installed Pyenv using brew and set path using

`echo 'eval "$(pyenv init --path)"' >> ~/.zshrc`

Now I deleted it with brew, and I got `.zshrc:1: command not found: pyenv` every time I opened my terminal. I understand that I need to simply remove the pyenv init invocations from my shell startup configuration. But can someone give me the right command line to do so? Thanks
I am on MacOS by the way

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Vim installed, you can use `vim ~/.zshrc` to open the file and then edit it out.

Comment: ```eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
alias python=/usr/bin/python3``` this is what I got with ```vim ~/.zshrc```, what should I change? Just delete first line?

Comment: Yes, if there's only one line in there, just remove that.

Comment: This may sound silly , but how can I save changes after I delete it? I just deleted it and closed the terminal, and when I open terminal again, command not found still there, and when I enter vim again, it says found a swap file by name"~/.zshrc.swp"

Comment: `:x`. It's not silly, it's a common problem. Don't worry. You may have to hit escape to be able to enter that though.